# Can an ISP lock your Cable Model MAC?

Tags: modem, mac-address

I was with Spectrum for few years. Recently, I moved to a new location where Spectrum does not have service, so I had to move my cable modem (which I bought, not rented), an Arris Surfboard SB6183, from Spectrum to Cox (the only provider in my new location).

I was on the phone with Spectrum for 4 hours to cancel my service and release my MAC to work with new provider. They said they did cancel my service and released my modem MAC id.

But it still did not work with Cox. I bought the same model from Best buy and it worked with Cox. So obviously something somewhere is wrong.

My questions are:

A) Can Spectrum lock my modem so that it cannot be used by some other provider?

B) Is there a way I can change the MAC id of my modem?

Comment: One ISP cannot MAC block connection to another ISP. Your issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: Could you know where the issue be? I am confused now as to why my modem would not work with other provider

Comment: Talk to your new ISP.

Comment: Did you activate your modem with your new provider?

Comment: Why were you asking Spectrum to release anything?  Cox activating a modem you purchased, instead of rented, has nothing to do with Spectrum.  *Have you confirmed the modem you purchased is on the list of supported modems that Cox supports?*

Comment: You did a factory reset on the modem prior to use with the new ISP right?

Answer (score 0):

The Media Access Control ('MAC') is burned into the firmware of your device, and cannot be permanently changed. There are apps for Linux, MacOS X, and Windows to 'spoof' a device's MAC, but I do not know if they are available for whatever OS your router runs.